# create a popup window with just a textview/string and a button SWIFT ios 8

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, popup, xcode6

I am very new to ios 8 and swift but I have not found a way to make a simple popup window whenever a button is pushed. I payed for tutorials and they still don't cover it. All i would like is for when the user pushes a button (the lowercase i in a circle) a small popup window with a textview that provides the user with instructions and a button below that textview that lets them close the popup.

So far it seems that what I need is to use a UIAlertViewController but every tutorial and example I have seen requires two buttons and is more of a one line thing than a paragraph type deal.

Can anyone show me how to make a popup window appear after pressing a button in swift programmatically and to have that popup hold just a textview and a button and then have that popup disapear when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `UIAlertController`, check this out:

```
@IBAction func popUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

//This is where you declare and initialize your `UIAlertController`
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Test Alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

//You give the `UIAlertController` an action, which basically has a cancel button, that just cancels out the popup
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

//this actually gets the `UIAlertController` on your screen when the button is pressed
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

***Tip***

Make sure you correctly *link* up your button to your `ViewController` through the **Main.storyboard**

Comment: Not a problem! Let me know if you run into trouble, I'll be here :) @KellysOnTop23

Comment: Isn't the question for a textview?